# ¿Cómo guardar un elemento del componente <select> en Angular en Base de datos con SpringBoot?

Tags: java, sql, angular, spring-boot, html-select

Tengo la siguiente tabla que muestra el listado de lo que hay en la tabla **CONTROL**, el campo **ESTADO** se muestra como una lista despegable con la descripcion de los estatus que hay en la tabla **ESTADO**, tengo en el **select**  el value 0 para que por Default tenga seleccionado el estatus actual que esta en la tabla CONTROL, y lo que quiero es que al seleccionar cualquier estatus se actualice en la base de datos

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
            <th scope="col">COMENTARIO</th>
            <th scope="col">HORA INICIO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contr of control">
            <td>{{contr.id}}</td>
            <td>
                <select class="select-css">
                    <option value="0">{{contr.cveEstado}}</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado">
                        {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>{{contr.comentario}</td>
            <td>{{contr.horaInicio}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tengo lo siguiente en mi componente.ts

```
control: Control[] = [];
controlModel: Control =  new Control();
estadoModel: Estatus[] = [];

constructor(private controlService: ControlService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerListaControl();
    this.obtenerListaEstado();
}
    


    private obtenerListaControl(){
    this.controlService.obtenerControl().subscribe(response => {
      this.control = response.data;
    });
   }

   private obtenerListaEstado(){
    this.controlService.obtenerEstatus().subscribe(resp => {
      this.estadoModel = resp.data;
    });
   }

   guardar(){
    this.controlService.updateEstado(this.controlModel).subscribe(data=>{
      this.controlModel=data;
    })
   }
```

El método **obtenerListaControl()** es para listar lo que hay en la tabla CONTROL, el método **obtenerListaEstado()** es para listar la descripcion de los Estados, ya que en la tabla **CONTROL** solo trae la clave del estado y no la descripcion  y el método **guardar()** que es para que realice la actualizacion en la BD y manda a llamar al servicio con el método **updateEstatus()**

en el service.ts

```
updateEstatus(control: Control){
    return this.httpClient.put<Control>(this.baseUrl+"/"+control.id,control);
  }
```

en mi backend tengo los siguientes querys, los que uso para mostrar la info. de la tabla CONTROL y de la tabla ESTADO

```
@Query(value = "SELECT C.ID, EST.DESCRIPCION AS CLAVE_ESTADO, C.COMENTARIO, C.HORA_INICIAL 
 FROM CONTROL C INNER JOIN ESTADO EST ON C.CLAVE_ESTADO= EST.CLAVE_ESTADO", nativeQuery = 
 true)
List<ControlEntity> consulta();


@Query(value = "SELECT EST.CLAVE_ESTADO, EST.DESCRIPCION FROM ESTADO EST", nativeQuery = true)
    List<EstadoEntity> findEstado();
```

y estas son las tablas

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name= "CONTROL")
    public class ControlEntity{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "CLAVE_ESTADO")
    private String claveEstado; 
    
    @Column(name = "COMENTARIO")
    private String comentario; 
    
    @Column(name = "HORA_INICIAL")
    private Date horaInicial;
    
    
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name= "ESTADO")
    public class EstadoEntity{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLAVE_ESTADO")
    private String claveEstado; 
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    private String descripcionEstado; 
    
    
    }
```

mi método en el Controller para la actualización es el siguiente

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ControlEntity actualizar(@RequestBody ControlEntity control,
            @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        control.setId(id);
        return controlService.actualizar(control);
    }
```

y al querer actualizar un estado seleccionado, me manda lo siguiente:

> Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"]

No se que estoy haciendo mal, lo que debo de actualizar en la tabla **CONTROL** es la claveEstado, como puedo actualizar corrctamente el registro?

Comment: Parece que nunca envías el valor del cambio, intenta agregando un `(change)`  en el `select` que estás usando para modificar los valores, change se activa cuando el usuario cambia un valor y se sale del elemento. Necesitarías algo así como `(change)=“cambios(valorCambiado)”`, no recuerdo bien pero creo que como se dispara cuando el usuario hace algo entonces tendrías que mandar el valor del evento.